# "Organize inputs" breaks script, what is going on?

Tags: python, python-import

A coworker send me a script that starts like this:

```
from ourlibA import *
from ourlibB import *
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.now()
```

when I invoke the script like that, it works nicely.

But I am using pycharm, and after make a few edits, I also used its "organize import" feature, which turned the imports into:

```
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime

from ourlibA import *

from ourlibB import *

print datetime.now()
```

And when I now run that changed script, I end up with:

> print datetime.now()
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Now I am simply baffled, leading to these questions:

- What exactly could be going on here? The import for `datetime` is still there, so where is that error coming from?
- Obviously, the problem must be coming out of the fact that the second examples imports our own libraries last, not first. But how exactly can I find out which part of our libraries causes this?

I understand that this isn't a full mcve, but these private libraries are huge, and private. I am more asking about how to approach such an "import order" issue in python in general.

( I am using python 2.7.17 )

Comment: Maybe, in `ourlibA` or `ourlibB`, there is some kind of import like `import datetime`? Or `import X as datetime`? As this would cause it to override the previous import as a new name for datetime is imported, which is the module `datetime`, and not the `datetime.datetime` one that was first imported

Answer (score 0):

I took a "brute force" approach, and simply, manually reviewed the import statements of the private libraries (recursively), to identify one that does

```
import datetime
```

Thus: when that library is imported last, it conflicts with the previous `from datetime import datetime` statement.

Two "quick solutions" (more: dirty hacks) work, by changing the client script:

- removing `from datetime import datetime`
- using the "full path" `print datetime.datetime.now()` instead

The "better" solution: to step back, and get rid of both `from X import *` wildcard statements. It takes a bit of time to identify all the specific names that are required, but it is definitely worth spending that time.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in my commend. Note that usually it is bad practice to do `from X import *`, one of the reasons is exactly this - it causes confusions and collisions between imports, and usually you'll import only what you need `from ourlibA import X,Y,Z` and so on (there are, of course, use cases for importing * though), thus resolving the issue of collisions, where you can also name the imports accordingly (`from ourlibA import X as ourlibA_X`)

Comment: In that case, you might want to put the asterisk imports first and only then your own file's imports, and not organize them automatically using PyCharm's functionality

Comment: Good you managed to replace, much better and clearer that way. I definitely never would use that, always explicitly is much better (Sometimes importing the module itself and accessing `outlibA.X()` and such.
I think your question is okay and explained well, and I'm guessing that if many people would find themselves in the same situation without finding help, they'd upvote.

Comment: @Zionsof Thank you very much for your helpful input. I also updated the answer to reflect the part about getting rid of the wildcard import.